# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml' despite having installed yaml and pyyaml

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, quarto

I have installed Quarto in VSCode on my M1 Mac.

When I try to render a qmd file into an html file ...

```
quarto render quarto_vscode.qmd
```

...I get a strange error message

```
Starting python3 kernel...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/quarto/share/jupyter/jupyter.py", line 21, in <module>
    from notebook import notebook_execute, RestartKernel
  File "/Applications/quarto/share/jupyter/notebook.py", line 14, in <module>
    from yaml import safe_load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I have confirmed via `conda list` that both yaml and pyyaml are installed to my virtual environment.

```
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py310h2aa6e3c_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h3422bc3_2    conda-forge
```

At this stage I am just trying to get Quarto to render so I have a very simple qmd file:

````
---
title: "VSCode Quarto Report"
date: "2023-01-07"
format: html
editor: source
include: TRUE 
echo: TRUE 
jupyter: python3
---

```{python}
print('hello')
```
````

Comment: Can you run in the terminal `quarto check` to know which version of quarto and its dependencies you're running. Also please provide information about the version of your visual studio code and your operating system.

Comment: Are you using jupyter or py script? Did you choose the conda interpreter or kernel?

Comment: I am facing the same issue after updating quarto to version 1.4

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, but I no longer face this issue. I have installed pyyaml, and I have also switched from x86 to arm version of python.